# Doxygen comment for angularJS function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, doxygen

I'm using angularJS and doxygen for my project.

In my angular controller, I've some functions defined like this:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
     /**
      * @param page String Page name
      * @ingroup API
      * @author Sylvain
      */
     $scope.prev = function(page) {
        ... 
     }

     ... other functions
}
```

I would like that doxygen understand this code as a function declaration.

I have tried to use the `@fn` command, but then doxygen concatenate all angular functions comments inside the documentation of `MyCtrl` function without creating a new function block.

Do you have an idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the $scope argument is confusing Doxygen.  If I change the name to just "scope" and I replace "page" with "scope" in your @param comment, then Doxygen works fine.  It produces a function declaration document section, with appropriate content.

Doxygen does not claim to support JavaScript, but it does work if the JavaScript does not look like PHP thanks to the $ symbol.

Maybe this link will help, too:  http://blog.coherent-labs.com/2012/10/documenting-javascript-with-doxygen.html